# GitLab - CI/CD : external public ressources issue

Tags: gitlab, public

I've build a test scenario for gitlab (.gitlab-ci.yml) but I've issue for some tests as they need to have an access on public ressources (provided by internet without limitation but specific url + port).

A simple test has validated the access blocked by the gitlab docker during the validation phase:

`$ wget http://url:port
--2018-07-03 13:42:06--  http://url:port/
Connecting to url:port... failed: Connection refused.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

ls of course validated on another server/pc/...

Someone has an idea on the 'howto' proceed to open this network flow?

Thanks for help and have a nice day ;-) !

Guillain